# Facing issues while setting up Zuul API gateway for a Node.js based microservice

Tags: node.js, centos7, netflix-zuul, zuul-ci

I want to set up Zuul API Gateway. I have followed the steps given in the [documentation](https://zuul-ci.org/docs/zuul/howtos/zuul-from-scratch.html). I am running zuul on CentOs 7. Following services are running:

- Zookeeper
- Nodepool-launcher
- Zuul-scheduler
- Zuul-executor
- Zuul-web

I have used nodepool static configuration, not the openstack configuration. Since I am new to Zuul or any API gateway, I am not being able to figure out what additional services will I need to get zuul running and to route the requests from zuul to the microservice. Any suggestions are most welcome!

P.S: I already have load-balancer in place. Will I still need to use Eureka service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am not familiar with CI/CD pipelines, I confused zuul-ci for zuul API Gateway. For future reference, the documentation that I followed is [this](https://zuul-ci.org/docs/zuul/howtos/zuul-from-scratch.html). If anyone is trying to implement zuul API gateway for microservices, the documentation to be followed is [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/). Several other useful links are mentioned in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) which could be handy for further information.